# Why is my loop in r is just running once?

Tags: r, for-loop

I asked a very similar question before but the answers i got dont seem to apply in this case. The aim of my code is primarily to take a file, manipulate it and the save the manipulated file over the old file. Unfortunately there are a lot of file so I have incorporated a for loop but it is stopping after just one run through the loop. I think my return function is in the right place and my for statement worked in a previous slightly different version of the script.
 Here is my code:

```
AddLatLon<- function(num, condition){


#Set working directiory 
# num is the number of files needing extraction e.g (3:5) , c(2,7)

connect <- file("./EOBS DATA/sources.txt", "r")
locdata <- readLines(connect)
close(connect)

info <- locdata[24:length(locdata)] # removes non data before the data begins



Infodata <- read.table(text = info, sep=',',fill=TRUE,colClasses='character',header ==TRUE )
InfoTable <- read.csv("./EOBS DATA/sources.csv")  
InfoTable$STAID <- as.numeric(InfoTable$STAID)



for(i in c(num)){
filename <-paste("./EOBS DATA/",condition, "_csv_data/", condition,i, ".csv", sep = "")


#if(i <10){
  #filename <- paste("./EOBS DATA/ECA_blend_", condition, "/" ,CONDITION, "_STAID00000", i, ".txt", sep = "")
#}
#if(i >=10 & i < 100){
  #filename <- paste("./EOBS DATA/ECA_blend_", condition, "/" ,CONDITION, "_STAID0000", i, ".txt", sep = "")
#}

#if(i>= 100 & i <1000){
  #filename <- paste("./EOBS DATA/ECA_blend_", condition, "/" ,CONDITION, "_STAID000", i, ".txt", sep = "")
#}
#if(i>= 1000){
  #filename <- paste("./EOBS DATA/ECA_blend_", condition, "/" ,CONDITION, "_STAID00", i, ".txt", sep = "")
#}
if(file.exists(filename) == FALSE) {
  next
}


#con <- file(filename, "r")
#data <- readLines(con)
#close(con)
#q <- data[21:length(data)] # removes non data before the data begins



#Impactdata <- read.table(text = q, sep=',',fill=TRUE,colClasses='character',header = TRUE )


x <- read.csv(filename)



point <- match(i, InfoTable$STAID) 
Lat <- InfoTable[point,5]
Lon <- InfoTable[point,6]

Lat <- as.character(Lat)
Lon <- as.character(Lon)


x$Lat <- Lat
x$Lon <- Lon   



x$X <- NULL
x$DATE<- as.Date(as.character(x$DATE), format='%Y%m%d')

Savename <- paste("./EOBS DATA/",condition, "_csv_data/", condition,i, ".csv", sep = "")   

if(condition == "rr"){
  condition <- "Precipitation"
}
if(condition == "tn"){
  condition <- "Minimum Temperature"
}
if(condition == "tx"){
  condition <- "Maximum Temperature"
}

names(x)<- c("Station_ID", "Source_ID", "Date(yyyy-mm-dd)", condition, "Quality_code(0='valid'; 1='suspect')", "Latitude", "Longitude")


write.csv(x, Savename)


} 
return(head(x))
}
```

Comment: If my comments did not answer your question, please show us how you called `AddLatLon` to test it (the exact command). And what makes you think it only ran one iteration?

Comment: Use `debug` .  As flodel pointed out, you may well not be calling the file names you think you are.    BTW, I'd recommend reversing your `if(file.exists(filename)==FALSE)` to `....TRUE` , thus eliminating the need for a `next` call (when it's FALSE the remainder of the code is skipped).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`num` is not defined, but from the name I'm pretty sure you want to be looping over `1:num`, not `c(num)`. So just replace:

```
for(i in c(num)){
```

with

```
for(i in 1:num)){
```

or

```
for(i in seq_len(num)){
```

Why `seq_len`? It will do the right thing if `num` is zero (no looping) or negative (throw an error).

Comment: Unfortunately this hasn't solved my problem and it still just loops once. I also like the c(num) as it allows me to select specific files

Comment: Then I don't see anything wrong with your code. You could put a `print(i)` at the top of your loop and you will see that it is indeed looping over all values. You could also check that it is creating all the files you expected. What might be the "problem" is with `return(head(x))`: it will return the head of the `x` from the last iteration, making you believe it only ran one iteration.

Comment: Another possibility is that most of the files do not exist. Try to add a warning to the `file.exists` piece, for example: `if(!file.exists(filename)) { warning(filename, " does not exist"); next; }`.

Comment: So I eventually found that the reason it was running once was that I was changing the name of the condition within the loop so that when it came round to using condition again for the next loop it was throwing up that the file didnt exist. Removing the if statements about condition solved my problem!

Comment: I see now, good find. Hopefully that `warning` I suggested put you on the right track.